# React Datepicker( can't get value of input)

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-redux

I am new in react. I need use [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker)

I want to get value of input, when I change date.
If i click on 20th October 2017, i want put 20th October 2017 in my variable.
But the main problem that I should work with component, not with input.

Before I just took value from state. Like this.state.value. But right now it is object(Moment) in state. And this object doesn't have value field.

There is my code:

```
export default class DatePicker extends Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    // this.props.date should looks like "29 November 2017 00:00"
    // second argument for moment() it is format of date, because RFC 2822 date time format
    this.state = {
        date: moment(this.props.value, 'LLL')
    };
}
handleChange = (date) => {
  // const valueOfInput = this.state.date  <--- I want string with date here
  console.log('this.state.date',this.state.date);
  this.setState({date: date});
};
render() {
    return <Form.Field>
              <Label>
                <Picker
                  selected={this.state.date}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  dateFormat="LLL"
                  locale={this.props.language}
                />
              </Label>
          </Form.Field>
```

[image]

Comment: What theme library are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use this:

```
handleChange = date => {
  const valueOfInput = date.format();
  ///...
};
```

Because this `datepicker` returns a `moment.js` object!

For more information, look into the moment.js [docs here](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: thanks!, i was struggling on this issue for like two days, such a life saver  :)

Comment: i get date.format() is not a function. do i have to install moment?

Comment: @justin did you figure out a solution?

Comment: This answer is incorrect for newer versions of react-datepicker as moment.js is no longer used, instead date-fns is used.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
<DatePicker 
   onChange={(value, e) => this.handleChange(value, e)}
   selected={this.state.inputValue} otherProps={here} 
/>

// you can access the value field in handleChange by e.target.value

handleChange(value, e) {
    console.log(value); // this will be a moment date object
    console.log(e.target.value); // this will be a string value in datepicker input field
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved for me by using the following:

```
handleDateChange = date => {
let selectedDateFromCalender = date.toUTCString();
this.setState({
      actualStartDate: selectedDateFromCalender,
  });}

<DatePicker
selected={this.state.startDate}
onChange={this.handleDateChange}/>
```

---

You can use the following methods as well, choose according to your requirement:

toISOString: "2020-10-05T09:10:38.000Z"

toJSON: "2020-10-06T09:09:16.000Z"

toUTCString: "Thu, 08 Oct 2020 09:11:24 GMT"

Comment: It will give you the selected date.

Comment: What's the point? "selected". My Typescript wants "selected" to be of type Date, not string?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the new value (once the user clicks on a new date from DatePicker) pass the event to the method.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {inputValue: moment(),} // this will set the initial date to "today", 
                                         // you could also put another prop.state value there
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  }


  handleChange(value) {
    console.log(value); // this will be a moment date object
    // now you can put this value into state
    this.setState({inputValue: value});
  }

  render(){
    ...
    <DatePicker 
       onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
       selected={this.state.inputValue} otherProps={here} />
    ...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The new version of react-datepicker library stopped using a moment.js object, so here is my solution if you want to get a formatted string representation of the date.

First import 
    `import format from "date-fns/format";`
Then

```
    <DatePicker 
       onChange={(value)=>this.handleChange(format(value, "yyyy/MM/dd", { 
       awareOfUnicodeTokens: true }))}
       dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
       selected={this.state.inputValue} otherProps={here} />
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getTime() helper function on your date object to get the millisecond timestamp for that specific date, which is a JavaScript number data type. Useful for saving data in the backend of your application. For example Flask Peewee ORM requires a timestamp to be saved for the DateTimeField.

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())

<DatePicker
  onSelect( date => {
    setStartDate(getTime(date))
  }
/>
```

source: https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.7/docs/getTime

Combine it with an effect to set the default state value to a timestamp on page load:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setStartDate(getTime(startDate))
  }, [])
```

Otherwise for your UI, you can use the format() helper function to get the string value of the given object, with any given format:

```
<h1>{format(startDate, "MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa")}</h1>
```

source: https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.7/docs/format

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I solved it by using the below solution. Please try it:

```
<p>{this.state.date.toLocaleDateString()}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="tdate" type="date" name="todate" onchange="getToDate(event);">

function getToDate(e){
 const tdate = e.target.value;

//alert(tdate);
//console.log(tdate);
//return tdate;
};
```

here i am trying to access "tdate" variable outside the function.